# user32.dll SendMessage command causes message-sending application to pause execution

Tags: c#, dllimport, user32

I am using the user32 SendMessage dll command to transmit commands to a windows application.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

One of those commands cause the application to display a modal box accepting input.

My question is: **Why does my application's code execution halt until the modal box of the other application is being closed?**

Is there a way to continue the execution of my application's code without getting disturbed by the pauses caused when sending a message using the user32.dll?

Comment: Run SendMessage from another thread

Comment: Could you show me how to do that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Parent windows generally wait for its modal (or child) windows to close before they are able to be used. Is there no way for you to make the new window not a child of the current?

Comment: The newly displayed window is not a child window of my application. My application only sends messages to a 3rd party application which in turn displays its own child window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SendMessage will block until the recipient of the call has completed processing the message.

You could instead use PostMessage which will allow your program to continue executing immediately after dispatching the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about threading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx)

Here is simple example:

```
using System.Threading;

public static void DoSendMessage() 
{
    SendMessage(...); 
}

public void RunSendMessage()
{
  ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(DoSendMessage);
  Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
  newThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do, PostMessage is another way :)

Comment: Ok, then that's what I need then. +1 for your answer as well, though. thank you!